# How can I sum one column from the same table, to produce three different aggregates, using Sequel ORM?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

My query is this:

```
DB[:expense_projects___p].where(:project_company_id=>user_company_id).
  left_join(:expense_items___i, :expense_project_id=>:project_id).
  select_group(:p__project_name, :p__project_id).
  select_more{count(:i__item_id)}.
  select_more{sum(:i__amount)}.to_a.to_json
```

which works.

However, payment methods include cash, card and invoice. So I would like to sum each of those for summary purposes to achieve a discrete total for payments by cash, card, and invoice repsectively. I included the following line into the query

```
select_more{sum(:i__amount).where(:i__mop => 'card')}.
```

and the error message was

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `where' for #<Sequel::SQL::Function:0x007fddd88b5ed0>:
```

so I created the dataset separately with

```
ds1 = expense_items.where(:mop=>'card', :expense_company_id=>user_company_id).sum(:amount)
```

and appended it, at the end of the original query, with

```
select_append{ds1}
```

which achieved partial success as the returned json is now:

```
{"project_name":"project 2","project_id":2,"count":4,"sum":"0.40501E3","?column?":"0.2381E2"}
```

as can be seen there is no name for this element which I need in order to reference it in my getJSON call. I tried to add an identifier by adding `___a`
to the ds1 query as below

```
ds1 = expense_items.where(:mop=>'card', :expense_company_id=>user_company_id).sum(:amount___a)
```

but that failed.

In summary, is this the right approach and, in any case, how can I provide an identifier when doing a sequel sum query? In other words `sum(:a_column).as(a_name)`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataset#sum returns the sum, not a modified dataset.  You probably want something like:

```
ds1 = expense_items.where(:mop=>'card', :expense_company_id=>user_company_id).select{sum(:amount)}
select_append{ds1.as(:sum)}
```

Comment: You da man Jeremy, as always. I am most grateful for help here. It works great and I can do it as many times as I like with different items, so the select_append{ds1.as(:sum)} can be as(:card_amount) and as(:invoice_amount) and so on. Just what I was after. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for approach ( better ask Jeremy Evans ) but it work.

You just change: .sum(... to .select_more{:amount___a).as(:desired_name)}

```
ds1 = expense_items.where(:mop=>'card',    :expense_company_id=>user_company_id).select_more{:amount___a).as(:desired_name)}
```

and actually get that desired_name in db response.

Comment: thanks I will test it out and coma back to comment or give it a "tick". Thank you for your time. How can I contact Jeremy?

Comment: thanks but I am afraid this doe snot work. "sum" is missing for a start so if I change to  select_more{sum(:amount___a).as(total_card))} I get a group by error. I had to change it quite  a bit anyway, I don't understand why :amount___a and not just :amount.

Comment: Hi I didn't try it so probably you are right. About "a__amount" it was my mistake I think it should be i__amount or just amount. Jeremy is author of Sequel you can find contact on him everywhere on the net.